# Automatically split a wav file at silences and name them automatically

Tags: audio, audacity, music-management

I would like to cut my recording of old audiotapes, etc. automatically at parts of silence.

The perfect tool would do this:

- a batch script, that splits the recording automatically at silence
- save them in separate files
- batch search for matching songs in a database like [midomi](http://www.midomi.com/) or [MusicBrainz](http://musicbrainz.org/) to autodetect  artists and tracknames
- name them accordingly

I use Ubuntu Linux, but it would also help if it is all Windows.

With Audacity it is possible to [split a recording into separate tracks](http://manual.audacityteam.org/o/man/splitting_a_recording_into_separate_tracks.html) but this is quite a lot of work by hand and it can't detect the artists and tracks automatically

Answer (score 0):

[Sound Forge](http://www.sonycreativesoftware.com/soundforgesoftware) or something can do this easily.

> search for matching songs in a database like midomi or MusicBrainz to autodetect artists and tracknames

Now you have a potential problem in your workflow. I notice the use of mixtapes in your question. If they are old tapes this might work, depending on the type of tape (cassette or 2 inch reel? "Mixtape" means little, but just going on the standard assumption that it is a TDK 90 or something here.)

Problem being: these sort of services don't work properly; it's not one or the other or any other. It's all of them. The simplest things like pitch or tempo or just background noise or EQ can completely throw these programs off – in my experience. Again, you said "tape", which implies any/all of these problems should be present assuming you can even get the bias and tape material correct. I use a Nakamichi deck for cassette tape capture in my studio; even with this it's hard to accomplish that.

Comment: I have some tape-recordings, some from Vinyl. But also mp3-mixes with only one track recorded from mp3-radio; I guess here they would work quite well.

Answer (score 0):

maybe hand fabricate a cue file, the splitter will separate them based on absolute time instead of silences.

Comment: Please be a bit more clear in your answer. Give an example on how to make such a cue file and how it would be easier or better than an automated solution.

Comment: still learning the code entry thing, took too long to fix it, i hope without breaks that it's sorta readable.